# Replace NA in one column with value form another column on above row

Tags: r

I want to replace my NA Dates with the Date in the row above, which is in another columnn. My data looks like this:

```
ID  Date_first  Date_last 
1   2020-01-01  2020-05-21
1   2020-05-21  2020-09-15
2   2019-06-01  2019-10-30
2   NA          2020-02-06
```

I want to replace the NA value in Date_first of ID 2 with the Date_last of the same ID in the row above (2019-10-30).
Date_first NAs only occur in the second row of an ID, it is never in the first row of an ID.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr, this can be done using `group_by`, `coalesce`, and `lag`, for example:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Date_first = coalesce(Date_first, lag(Date_last))) %>% ungroup()
```